# How to enable and restart a systemd service after changes to their configuration

Tags: ansible, systemd

Given a set of previous task whose results I [register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditions-based-on-registered-variables), I want to:

- Enable my target service.
- Restart/reload it when any of the dependencies have changed.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```yaml
- name: "Enable and (re)start service {{ service_name|mandatory }}"
  systemd:
    name: "{{ service_name }}"
    daemon_reload: "{{ restart }}"
    enabled: yes
    state: "{{ restart|ternary('restarted', 'started') }}"
  vars:
    restart: "{{ registered|flatten|selectattr('changed')|length > 0 }}"
```

where `registered` contains a list of the registered dependencies, as in:

```yaml
vars:
  registered: "{{ [registered_outcome_1, ...] }}"
```

The `|flatten` expression ensures that it also works with [looped](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) tasks.

I also found useful to combine this with [looking up the registered variables by their names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72502938/1333025) so that I can just list names of registered variables instead of constructing the a list using `{{ [ ... ] }}`.

---

Even a nicer solution would be to run [`systemctl reload-or-restart ...`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#reload-or-restart%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6):

> Reload one or more units if they support it. If not, stop and then start them instead. If the units are not running yet, they will be started.

But [this isn't supported](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/71969) by Ansible at the moment.

Comment: This is usually done with a handler being notified.

Comment: Yes, that's another option. But I needed the services to be enabled and started at specific points in the playbook. Perhaps I could have used [`flush_handlers`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#controlling-when-handlers-run).